# String manipulation in Bash with prefixes

Tags: string, bash

I have a String with the folowing String : `aaaccbbaabbbb`

I need to either drop the front aaa's or the character sequence in the back bbbb's. I've tried `resString=(${resString%%b*b})` which resString is `aaaccbbaabbbb` is turned into `aaaccbbaa`. But I need to save the deleted bbbb's into a file. Is there a way to inverse the outcome of `resString=(${resString%%b*b})` to get the `bbbb` in a file. I've tried working with ## manipulation but it's such a hassle since I only need the repetition in the front or at the back of the String.

Comment: Do the stripping then use the result to strip itself off the front of the original variable and you get the bit you stripped off in the first step.

Comment: @EtanReisner That's a nice idea I could never taught of after so much hours of programming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: try `resString =~ .*(b+)$; resString=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`

Comment: @EtanReisner I think you could write that comment as answer.

Comment: @RodneySalcedo For it to have been a good answer it would have wanted to have the code (and output from each step) and I didn't have the time to sit down and write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a whole new approach using `${//}`.

It is fully **automatic**, it finds which is the first char, and which is the last.
With that set, it works its magic to select runs in the front and runs in the back.
Of course, you need to edit the program to choose which parts you do need to send to file, or print, or anything else. I hope you could do that part of the job.

This seems to work with any string (even repeated chars):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

a=(aaaccbbaabbbb aaabbbbaaaa abababbbb bbbaaabbb aaaaaa aaabbbbaaaa)

for resString in "${a[@]}"; do

    echo
    echo "String   :$resString:"
    l="$((2+${#resString}))"

    frontchar=${resString:0:1}         ; printf "%s%-${l}s\n" "Frontchar" ":$frontchar:"
    backchar=${resString:0-1:1}        ; printf "%s%${l}s\n"  "Backchar " ":$backchar:"
    head="${resString/%[^$frontchar]*}"; printf "%s%-${l}s\n" "head     " ":$head:"
    tail="${resString/#*[^$backchar]}" ; printf "%s%${l}s\n"  "tail     " ":$tail:"

    prefix="${resString%$tail}"       ; printf "%s%-${l}s\n" "prefix  " ":$prefix:"
    suffix="${resString#$head}"        ; printf "%s%${l}s\n"  "suffix   " ":$suffix:"

    echo "Using the head/suffix  value: $head -- $suffix"
    echo "Using the prefix/tail value: $prefix -- $tail"
done
```

Running it, you get:

```sh
String   :aaabbbbaaaa:
Frontchar:a:
Backchar           :a:
head     :aaa:
tail            :aaaa:
prefix  :aaabbbb:
suffix      :bbbbaaaa:
Using the head/suffix  value: aaa -- bbbbaaaa
Using the prefix/tail value: aaabbbb -- aaaa


String   :aaaccbbaabbbb:
Frontchar:a:
Backchar             :b:
head     :aaa:
tail              :bbbb:
prefix  :aaaccbbaa:
suffix      :ccbbaabbbb:
Using the head/suffix  value: aaa -- ccbbaabbbb
Using the prefix/tail value: aaaccbbaa -- bbbb


String   :abababbbb:
Frontchar:a:
Backchar         :b:
head     :a:
tail          :bbbb:
prefix  :ababa:
suffix    :bababbbb:
Using the head/suffix  value: a -- bababbbb
Using the prefix/tail value: ababa -- bbbb


String   :aaaaaa:
Frontchar:a:
Backchar      :a:
head     :aaaaaa:
tail     :aaaaaa:
prefix  ::
suffix         ::
Using the head/suffix  value: aaaaaa --
Using the prefix/tail value:  -- aaaaaa
```

Comment: It still has the same problem where it removes the whole string in the scenario aaabbbbaaaa or bbbaaabbb.

Comment: Now it works like a charm! Thanks for the long and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use bash regex matching:

```
resString='abababbbb'
if [[ $resString =~ [^b](b+)$ ]] ; then      
  resString=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
echo $resString
```

This prints `bbbb`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter expansion with extended globbing:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob          # Turn extended globbing on.

s=aaaccbbaabbbb

prefix=${s%%[^a]*}        # Remove everything from the first non-"a".
prefix_rest=${s##+(a)}    # Remove all a's at the beginning.

suffix=${s##*[^b]}        # See above.
suffix_rest=${s%%+(b)}

[[ $prefix$prefix_rest == $s ]] || echo Wrong prefix
[[ $suffix_rest$suffix == $s ]] || echo Wrong suffix

echo "$prefix : $prefix_rest"
echo "$suffix_rest : $suffix"
```

Comment: I am having problems with the line `prefix_rest=${s##+(a)}` it doesn't work

Comment: I fixed it with `prefix_rest=${s##*(a)}` instead. Thanks for the answer anyways it was clear and helped a lot.

Comment: when my string in your example `s=aaaabbbaaa` the `prefix=${s%%[^a]*}` works fine and results in `aaaa` but the `prefix_rest=${s##+(a)}` doesn't do anything at all. My solution btw is broken too. `prefix_rest=${s##*(a)}` deletes every a in the sentence and everything between it. So my result turns empty.

Comment: @HazinC.: For `aaaabbbaaa`, I'm getting `aaaa : bbbaaa` and `aaaabbbaaa :` which I think is correct. Or did I get the specification wrong?